# Generated code preview in netbeans. How to make effect like that?

Tags: java, netbeans, jtextpane, jeditorpane, hint

Some time ago I saw a nice effect in netbeans IDE. When my cursor stops on the `Generated Code` text (e.g. in generated `JFrame`), some kind of hint (preview of generated code) is visible (has grey background).
I searched it and I didn't found anything. **My question is what is that component and how does it works?** I suspect that is specific TextPane/EditorPane or something like that. 
[image]

EDIT:

Yea, this is a **JToolTip**, and here is some extra info:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/346510/GUI/java/Customizing-JToolTip

[Book](http://books.google.com/books?id=YPjZNlEgAMcC&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=jtooltip%20set%20component&source=bl&ots=GO5qm-g_fd&sig=EoEY8R-FUsZ4AVPdNcF6RJM8Szc&hl=pl&ei=8lLWTtXkD4jChAf3mKBz&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=7&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=jtooltip%20set%20component&f=false) page: 85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is a [JToolTip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolTip.html). The second one seems to be a `JToolTip` as well, but with formatted code and a different background color, at least from the screenshot you have linked to.